# Route persistent URL asp classic to MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp-classic

We are trying to convert an old classic asp site in MVC.
For multiple reasons we have to convert this site page by page leaving the not converted pages active on the same site.
Since there are many references to our URLs on the web, we need to retain the same URL format as before (example: domain/page.htm).
There is a way to do it on RouteConfig.cs ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"leaving the not converted pages active on the same site"* ?

Comment: The answer to your question is *yes*, but it is hard to elaborate more than that without understanding why it is a problem for you.

Comment: Check out the docs for MVC routing. https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing if you have some code you've tried and have questions about that, feel free to post it and ask a specific question. we can't help you without seeing what you've tried.